# Get finished level distribution across the database

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

I have a table that stores data of players game sessions. I need to count how many players finished each level of a game.

Table have this structure`

```
player_id, player_level, online_time, offline_time, register_time
7461919470860005376, 9, 21/06/19 20:22, 21/06/19 23:55, 20/06/19 18:22
```

What I was trying to do is getting max level for each `player_id`

Like this

```
SELECT x1.level, count(*)
FROM
(
SELECT player_id, max(player_level) as level
FROM session_end
GROUP BY player_id
) x1
GROUP BY level
```

Now, knowing that, I need to somehow add up players that have max level == 2 to the row of max level == 1, because of the fact that if player finished level 2, it means that it finished level 1 and so on.

How could I do that using PSQL-syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT x1.level, count(*), SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY x1.level)
FROM (SELECT player_id, max(player_level) as level
      FROM session_end
      GROUP BY player_id
     ) p
GROUP BY level;
```